# OpenMP parallelizaiton in Linux using Makefile

Tags: openmp

I am new to the openmp parallelization, and will be thankful if someone can provide advice.

My target is to enable openmp parallelization and reduce the simulation timing by increasing the number of threads.

I am using intel compiler in linux to proceed with openmp parallelization by using a makefile.

The makefile is as following.

```
# for ifort
ifeq (${FC},ifort)
    MKLROOT = /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64
        FFLAGS += -I${MKLROOT}/include/intel64 -I${MKLROOT}/include
        LDFLAGS += -L${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64 -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -qopenmp -liomp5 -lpthread -lm -ldl 
endif
```

While I run this script, if I increase the number of threads, then there is no particular effect on the parallelization timing. I was wondering if there is any problem in the script.

Can someone guide please? Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have OpenMP compiler directives inside your code? If so, then you'll need `-qopenmp` in your `FFLAGS` as well. Furthermore, all your MKL-related flags could be replaced by `-mkl=parallel` in both `FFLAGS` and `LDFLAGFS`

Comment: @Gilles You're assuming that MKL will be done outside OpenMP? If the whole application is OMP-parallelized you want single threaded mkl.

Comment: @Gilles Thank you for the advice. My source program contains OpenMP compiler directives. In this case, if my understanding about your advice is correct then FFLAGS should be as following:

        FFLAGS += -I${MKLROOT}/include/intel64 -I${MKLROOT}/include -qopenmp

Please correc me if I am wrong. Thank you

Comment: I'd say from what you indicated that what you'd need would be `FFLAGS += -I${MKLROOT}/include -qopenmp` and `LDFLAGS += -mkl=parallel -qopenmp`. And then as @VictorEijkhout mentioned, if your calls to parallel MKL functions are done inside OpenMP parallel regions, you'd better be careful. You might even consider replacing the `-mkl=parallel` by `-mkl=sequential` in that case.